# WebView media content stops when the screen is locked ( activity's onStop is called)

Tags: android, webview, media, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an App that plays a video inside a `WebView` on my MainActivity. The problem I am having is that the video is pausing whenever I lock the screen (Activity's `onStop` is called, that is when the video in the `WebView` is paused).

But this behavior only occurs on **Apis >= Lollipop(5.0)**.

I searched everywhere for a solution, but I could not find anything. I just want the video to keep playing even when the user is on LockScreen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your `WebView` is pausing because of the onStop, you can override onWindowVisibilityChanged from WebView:

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
        if (visibility != View.GONE) super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this pauses the video when the screen is unlocked again.

Comment: @SrujanBarai also add if (visibility != View.GONE && visibility != View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: The solution is working fine but make sure that you don't call webView.onResume() and         webView.onPause()